# append data to a formatted excel

Tags: python, excel, append

I'd like to append some data to an Excel file:

```
import os
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd as ExcelRead
def write_append(file_name):
    values = ["Ann", "woman", 22, "UK"]
    r_xls = ExcelRead.open_workbook(file_name,formatting_info=True,on_demand=True)
    r_sheet = r_xls.sheet_by_index(0)
    rows = r_sheet.nrows
    w_xls = copy(r_xls)
    sheet_write = w_xls.get_sheet(0)
    for i in range(0, len(values)):
        sheet_write.write(rows, i, values[i])
    w_xls.save(file_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_append("./bzxx.xls")
```

but got error result as follows:

```
D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\Scripts\python.exe
E:/Project/Finance/code/financeSystem/temp/copyfile.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/Project/Finance/code/financeSystem/temp/copyfile.py", line 36, in <module>
    write_append("./bzxx.xls")
    File "E:/Project/Finance/code/financeSystem/temp/copyfile.py", line 31,  in write_append
    w_xls.save(file_name)
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 696, in save
doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 653, in get_biff_data
before += self.__all_fonts_num_formats_xf_styles_rec()
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 556, in __all_fonts_num_formats_xf_styles_rec
return self.__styles.get_biff_data()
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 185, in get_biff_data
      result += self._all_num_formats()
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Style.py", line 209, in _all_num_formats
      result += NumberFormatRecord(fmtidx, fmtstr).get()
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 785, in __init__
ufmtstr = upack2(fmtstr)
    File "D:\Python\Environment\env_finance\lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
  TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

The Excel is formatted which can't be changed. I want to add some data to it; can you help?